# Regarding the surjectivity of a function in a functional equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

Given $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ such that $$f (x+f (x)+2y)=2x+2f (y),$$ how can we prove that  the function  $f (x)+x$ is surjective ?

The author has just mentioned that the function  $f (x)+x$ is surjective without providing slightest of any hint.
Following is the picture of the problem with solution

[image: th pic]

A pedantic and easiest possible explanation and proof for the same would be helpful.

Comment: The function $f(x)+x$ is surjective, because for every image $y=2x$, there exists a preimage $f(y/2)=f(x)$, courtesy of $f(f(x))+f(x)=2x$

Comment: To be more explicit, write $\Phi(t):=f(t)+t$, then to show that $\Phi$ is surjective, we need to show that $\forall~y\in\Bbb R~\exists~t\in\Bbb R$ st $\Phi(t)=y$. You can write $y=2x$ for some $x\in\Bbb R$ and take $t=f(x)$ to show surjectivity.

Comment: Could you please tell that what do you mean by "courtesy of $f(f(x))+f(x)=2x$" in your 1st comment??

Comment: Also why did you take $y=2x $  in your  2nd comment ??

Comment: There's a typo, the problem in the image says $f(x+f(x)+2y)=2x+2\color{red}{f(f(y))}$, while the post says $f(x+f(x)+2y)=2x+2\color{red}{f(y)}$.

Answer (score 0):

This will be just copying the image, but I'll just write it down step by step.

> $f: \Bbb{Q} \to \Bbb{Q}, \; P(x, y): \;f(x+f(x)+2y)=2x+2f(f(y)).$

\begin{align}
P(0, 0): \; & f(f(0))=2f(f(0)) \Rightarrow f(f(0))=0. \\
\therefore \; & \exists \; t \text{ s.t. } f(t)=0. \\
P(t, 0): \; & f(t+f(t))=2t, t=0. \\
\therefore \; & f(x) = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=0. \tag{1}\label{1} \\
\ \\
P(0, y): \; & f(2y)=2f(f(y)). \\
\therefore \; & f(x+f(x)+2y)=2x+f(2y). \\
\ \\
\text{let } Q(x, y): \; & f(x+f(x)+y)=2x+f(y). \\  
\ \\
Q(x, 0): \; & f(x+f(x))=2x. \\
Q(x, y+f(y)): \; & f(x+f(x)+y+f(y))=2x+f(y+f(y))=2x+2y. \tag{2}\label{2} \\
y=-x \text{ in } (\ref{2}): \; & f(f(x)+f(-x))=0. \\
\text{by } (\ref{1}), \; & f(x)+f(-x)=0, f(-x)=-f(x). \\
\ \\
Q(x, -x): \; & f(f(x))=2x+f(-x)=2x-f(x). \\
\therefore \; & f(f(x))+f(x)=2x. \\
\ \\
\text{let} \; & f(x)+x=g(x). \\
\Rightarrow \; & g\left(f\left(\frac x 2\right)\right)=f\left(f\left(\frac x 2 \right)\right)+f\left(\frac x 2 \right) = x. \\
\therefore \; & g(x): \text{ surjective}. \blacksquare
\end{align}